# How to move all the pointers from one vector to another?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

Basically what I want to do is remove some of the pointers inside my vector, but I found out that it can be quite slow to do that in the middle of the vector.

So I have a vector that already has data inside:

`std::vector<Class*> vec1; // This already contains pointers`

I'll iterate through vec1 and will add some of the pointers to another vector (vec2): `vec2.push_back(vec1.at(index))`

Now I would like to do is something like `vec1 = vec2` but I don't know if this is the better (effecient) way to do that.

What would be the best way to do that?

I tried:

1. While looping through vec1 simply erasing what I need to remove from it:

   `it = vec1.erase(it)`
2. While looping through vec1 moving the last item to the actual index and poping_back

   `vec1.at(index) = vec1.back();
   vec1.pop_back();`
3. Setting some attribute on the object the pointer is pointing while looping through vec1 and than using `std::remove_if`

   `vec1.erase(std::remove_if(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), shouldBeRemoved), vec1.end());`
4. Now I'm trying to generate a new vector while looping through vec1 and adding the pointers I want to keep, then "swapping" or "moving" the contents of this new vector to vec1.

Apparently when doing it the 4th way, the pointers get invalidated :(

I would love to see what you guys suggest me. A big thank you to everyone that is willing to help!

Comment: if you need to change the content of your data container frequently, use one which fits to this requirement. maybe a std::list helps for performance reasons. std::vector is definitely not made for your use case!

Comment: "move all the pointers" is quite different from "move some pointers", you should fix question title (or body)

Comment: Your problem is actually a performance problem, not "how to move / remove pointers". I would suggest that you rephrase your question to "how to efficiently remove pointer from container"

Comment: So it a vector with probably around 100 pointers and I'll loop through it every second, I used list for a while but I read in some places that vector could help me with better cache use than list, thats why i'm trying it.
I'll need to remove some of theese pointers sometimes and i'll add new ones outside the loop, is it no valid to use vector here?

Comment: Without knowing how your did #4, the reasons your "pointers get invalidated" will forever be a mystery. Pointers don't get invalidated unless *you* somehow invalidate them (dangle them, delete their referred objects, etc). Of the options you've shown, I'd use #3, with the forefront being the "Setting some attribute" being pointless. If you can conditionally set that attribute, you can program the same condition to just remove the pointer as part of a remove-erase idiom.

Comment: "Apparently when doing it the 4th way, the pointers get invalidated :(" I think it is clear that I don't know how to properly move the pointers. And yes, I'm moving all the pointers from vec2 to vec1, its just that I could ask this question probably 3 different ways.

Comment: For a performance problem, we'd need a [mcve]. We cannot answer a specific question with generic ideas of what your code looks like.

Comment: #2 will change the order of the items in the vector.  If you don't care about the order, then why are you using a vector?

Comment: You should [edit] your post to fix the somewhat misleading title.

Comment: Have you done any benchmark ? Compared std::list std::vector in your specific use case ? Optimisation are often situationnal.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to conditionally remove items from a vector. This algorithm will shift items that need to be kept over to the front. Follow it up with a [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)  call to actually remove the items not shifted to the front.

This is similar to your option 3, but you don't need to set an attribute first - just use a predicate that determines if the item should be kept or not, and avoid having to pass over the vector twice.

If you don't want to do it in-place, but want to fill a new vector, then [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) does that.

Comment: Things not doing what they're called doesn't make them efficient - it makes them badly named; but given OP has said that efficiency is the problem, but the order of things in the vector is not; std::remove_if is not the most efficient way

Comment: @UKMonkey : then why not create your own answer with he more efficient way ?

Comment: @JeJo : no it won't. A swap is more expensive than a single copy (it typically needs 3 copies), and erasing one item at a time from the end is more expensive than erasing multiple items at once.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Efficiency is hard to comment on w/o measuring.  Is erasing one item at a time really less efficient than erasing multiple items at once?  After all, you are tracking the same information that vector would internally be tracking; namely, where the useful end of the vector is.  Is it really any more efficient for you to decrement a counter/pointer than for vector to do it internally?

Comment: @Nevin : it is more expensive to decrement a counter/pointer multiple times than to do it once, yes. Sure, optimizations at all levels can mitigate (and potentially even completely eliminate) that difference. But that won't make the overall proposed alternative more efficient (barring special cases, like deleting from the front, or deleting very few items).

Answer (score 3):

Removing things from a vector should be done with the `erase remove idiom`

It is well covered here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

The basic idea is to shift the elements first and then erase the unneeded items which is faster than erasing and shifting each individual element which is done as from the example with:

```
v.erase( std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), 5 ), v.end() );
```

But in general: If you have a lot of add/erase steps in your algorithm, you should use a std::list where removing elements in the middle is much cheaper at all.

Comment: Because CPU caching works much better with contiguous blocks of memory it is often still much faster to add and remove elements from the middle of a `std::vector`, compared to `std::list`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo Another alternative could be a `std::deque`.

Comment: Galik's right - switching to `std::list` should be thought about carefully, considering not only how many elements you need to remove, how often, and from where, but also the potentially astronomical impact all the new indirection may have on performance. I'm not sure that I've ever created a large `std::list`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm still looking for a real-life example where a `std::list` is faster than a `std::vector`. I've asked around to experienced (note: good != experienced) developers to provide me an example. None survived the benchmark.

Comment: @YSC: Sounds about right. Cache locality is, in practically every real case I've at least personally experienced, far and away the biggest consideration here.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt #2 suggests that you're not interested in the order of the elements.  remove_if will suffer performance problems as it will maintain the order of the items that you don't delete; meaning you could do a substantial number of shifts to maintain this order.

The swapping and popping will suffer the problem that repeatedly popping the back isn't required - it could resize the vector or do other things.

As such, by combining the ideas - of swapping the "last not swapped out" (ie last the first time, 2nd last the 2nd etc) and then at the end erasing the end items once complete; you should have the fastest algorithm.

Some of the comments suggest that a copy is faster than a swap; and while true when doing a single copy; for a vector when you're copying multiple elements multiple times; the swap will be significantly faster.

Comment: `std::remove_if` will only do at most n-1 copies (with n the size of the vector) - that's not "a substantial number of shifts". A copy is done for every item for which the predicate returns `false` (assuming it's not already in he right position), and that's it. No "copying multiple elements multiple times". That said, your approach can still be faster in specific cases (deleting from the front of the vector eg., or deleting very few items), so it can be desirable depending on the op's use case.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker  It goes from O(Number of items removed) to O(Size Of Vector)  -  One is always smaller than the other.